# How to resolve the following JS error?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a simple html + js script which has a few images on left sides and one less on right side and on clicking a correct element(last child of the div) adds the images on both right and left sides(+5 everytime).
Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        img {
            position:absolute;
        }

        div {
            position:absolute;
            width:500px; 
            height:500px;
        }

        #rightSide { left: 500px; 
            border-left: 1px solid black; 
        }


    </style>

    </head>
    <body onload="generateFaces()">
        <h1>Matching Game</h1>
        <div id="leftSide"></div>
        <div id="rightSide"></div>
        <script>
            var numberOfFaces = 5;
            var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
            generateFaces(theLeftSide);
            function generateFaces(theLeftSide) {
                for (var i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
                var img = document.createElement("IMG");
                img.src="smile.png";
                img.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 401);
                img.style.height = 100;
                img.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 401);
                theLeftSide.appendChild(img);
            };

        }

            leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
            var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
            leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
            theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);

            var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick= function nextLevel(event){ 
                theLeftSide.innerHTML='';
                theRightSide.innerHTML='';
                event.stopPropagation(); 
                numberOfFaces += 5; 
                generateFaces(); 

            /*  while(theLeftSide.firstChild)
                {
                    theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild);
                }
                while(theRightSide.firstChild)
                {
                    theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild);
                }*/1

            };
            theBody.onclick = function gameOver() {
                alert("Game Over!");
                theBody.onclick = null;
                theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
                }; 

        </script>



        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However it's giving me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined
```

Also I have written code for deleting the images, this is also not working.

Comment: `onload="generateFaces()"`. You're passing `undefined` to the function and  `theLeftSide.appendChild(img);` throws an error

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Remove the `onload` part as you're calling `generateFaces(theLeftSide)` in the script block (btw. what's with the second closing `</script>` at the bottom?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    /*img {
        position:absolute;
    }*/

    div {
        position:absolute;
        width:500px; 
        height:500px;
    }

    #rightSide { left: 500px; 
        border-left: 1px solid black; 
    }


</style>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Matching Game</h1>
    <div id="leftSide"></div>
    <div id="rightSide"></div>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        var numberOfFaces = 5;
        var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
        generateFaces();
        function generateFaces() {
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
                (function(i) {
                    var img = document.createElement("img");
                    img.src="smile.png";
                    // img.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 401);
                    img.style.height = 100;
                    // img.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 401);
                    console.log('img');
                    theLeftSide.appendChild(img);
                }(i));
                console.log("running");

            };
        }

        leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
        var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
        leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
        theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);

        var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick= function nextLevel(event){ 
            theLeftSide.innerHTML='';
            theRightSide.innerHTML='';
            event.stopPropagation(); 
            numberOfFaces += 5; 
            generateFaces(); 

          while(theLeftSide.firstChild)
            {
                theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild);
            }
            while(theRightSide.firstChild)
            {
                theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild);
            }

        };
        theBody.onclick = function gameOver() {
            alert("Game Over!");
            theBody.onclick = null;
            theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
            }; 

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

setting the images to `absolute` would put the images over eachother

Comment: `window.onload = generateFaces(theLeftSide);` isn't necessary because `generateFaces` is already called at the top of the script block.

Comment: I did what andreas suggested but when I click after game over now new faces are being generated.What to do?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Answer (score 0):

change your function parameter name

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        img {
            position:absolute;
        }

        div {
            position:absolute;
            width:500px; 
            height:500px;
        }

        #rightSide { left: 500px; 
            border-left: 1px solid black; 
        }


    </style>

    </head>
    <body onload="generateFaces()">
        <h1>Matching Game</h1>
        <div id="leftSide"></div>
        <div id="rightSide"></div>
        <script>
            var numberOfFaces = 5;
            var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
            generateFaces(theLeftSide);
            function generateFaces(the_Lef_tSide) {
                for (var i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
                var img = document.createElement("IMG");
                img.src="smile.png";
                img.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 401);
                img.style.height = 100;
                img.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 401);
                theLeftSide.appendChild(img);
            };

        }

            leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
            var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
            leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
            theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);

            var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick= function nextLevel(event){ 
                theLeftSide.innerHTML='';
                theRightSide.innerHTML='';
                event.stopPropagation(); 
                numberOfFaces += 5; 
                generateFaces(); 

            /*  while(theLeftSide.firstChild)
                {
                    theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild);
                }
                while(theRightSide.firstChild)
                {
                    theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild);
                }*/1

            };
            theBody.onclick = function gameOver() {
                alert("Game Over!");
                theBody.onclick = null;
                theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
                }; 

        </script>



        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why and how does it affect?

Comment: No.In facte I have much less images on right than is required.

Comment: please provide clear description about your program. if we click on body it says "Game Over!".